# For loop Python OpenPyXL in Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

**Context**

Got a variable Output that contains text mentioned below. However, I want to insert each Output line on each A-row in Excel. How do I do this?

**Output**

- Text 1
- Text 2
- Text 3

**Current Code**

```
# Open Workbook
wb = load_workbook('Fortimail-config.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Create a workbook sheet name.
sheet = wb['Sheet']

sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = output

wb.save("Fortimail-config.xlsx")
```

**What I get**

- A1 = Text 1 Text 2 Text 3

**What I want**

- A1 = Text 1
- A2 = Text 2
- A3 = Text 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = output` here the code is assigning value to row 1 and column 1. Therefore this will map to excel cell `A1`

Assuming `output` variable is an array; you can append it to the sheet using `sheet.append()` and it will add the array to each row.

**For example:**

```
output = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']

wb = load_workbook('Fortimail-config.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

# Create a workbook sheet name.
sheet = wb['Sheet']

sheet.append(output)

wb.save("Fortimail-config.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and your answer. I just tried it your way but the data is now moving from A1 B1 C1 etc.

Comment: sorry I may have misread the question. If you replace output = ['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3'] with output = [['Text 1', 'Text 2', 'Text 3']] (double brackets) you should see all data on row A